# What is the diffrence between JsObject and JsValue in Scala?

Tags: json, scala, playframework

**JsObject** and **JsValue** solves almost the same purpose but in JsObject

```
val data[JsObject] = Json.obj("id1"-> "some_id1")
val newData[JsObject] = data ++ Json.obj("id"-> "some_id")
```

we can add a new key-value pair in **JsObject** but I still haven't figure out how to add a key-value pair in **JsValue**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do more with `JsObject` because it is a subclass of `JsValue` that represents a JSON object (`{...}`). `JsValue` can be a string, numeric, object or array. Therefore you can't assume that it has key value pairs. If you have a `val x: JsValue`  that you know is a `JsObject` you can use `x.as[JsObject]` to cast it or if you're not sure it's a `JsObject` you can use `x.asOpt[JsObject]` to get an `Option[JsObject]`.

Comment: @simon This answer implies that you cannot add a key/value pair to a `JsValue` is that correct?

Comment: @franklin If you have a `JsValue` (let's call it `x`) that you know is a `JsObject` you can cast like `x.as[JsObject]` and then add key-value pairs. Otherwise you cannot add key-value pairs